# Find f'(x) at the given value of x

Tags: calculus, limits, derivatives

Find $f^\prime (x)$ at the given value of $x$:

$f(x)=3\sqrt{x}$

Find $f^\prime (5)$

For this one in my attempt to find the derivative I ended up with "$9/0$" which would lead me to believe that the value does not exist at $f^\prime (5)$. I was wondering if this was correct and if not how I would approach this question differently.

$\lim_{h\to0} \frac{3\sqrt{x+h}-3\sqrt{x}}{h} \cdot \frac{3\sqrt{x+h}-3\sqrt{x}}{3\sqrt{x+h}-3\sqrt{x}}$

$\lim_{h\to0} \frac{9(x+h)-9x}{h(3\sqrt{x+h}{-3\sqrt{x}})}$

Comment: $f'$ has a value at $5$. As for a different approach to the question: start by showing us the approach that didn't work.

Comment: Note that $\lim \limits_{x\to 5}\left(\dfrac{f(x)-f(5)}{x-5}\right)=\lim \limits_{x\to 5}\left(\dfrac{f(x)-f(5)}{\left(\sqrt x-\sqrt 5\right)\left(\sqrt x+\sqrt 5\right)}\right)$.

Comment: You should have multiplied by $3\sqrt{x+h}+3\sqrt{x}$ [top and bottom] at the first step in order to wind up with $9h$ on top. With the $+$ instead of $-$ it's the "conjugate".

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since you're using the formal definition of the derivative here, given $f(x)=3\sqrt{x}$, we know that

$$
\begin{align*}
f'(x)&=\lim_{h\to0} \frac{f(x+h)-f(x)}{h} \\
&= \lim_{h\to0} \frac{3\sqrt{x+h}-3\sqrt{x}}{h}\\
&= 3 \cdot \lim_{h\to0} \frac{\sqrt{x+h}-\sqrt{x}}{h}\\
\end{align*}
$$

We can then multiply the numerator and the denominator by the conjugate:

$$
f'(x)= 3 \cdot \lim_{h\to0} \frac{\sqrt{x+h}-\sqrt{x}}{h} \cdot \frac{\sqrt{x+h}+\sqrt{x}}{\sqrt{x+h}+\sqrt{x}}\\
$$

Try simplifying from here.

Comment: I think I have arrived at an answer but why did you elect to take out the 3 instead of multiplying using the 3 as I have edited my problem to show what I did above?

Comment: Just for simplicity's sake, so that the algebra within the limit wouldn't be as messy. Keeping the 3 inside the limit works fine.

Comment: oh okay thank you I understand now that the answer would be 3/2square root 5

Comment: Yep, that's correct!